# Does looking at a Django model's fk_id attribute trigger a database lookup?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a script that needs to go through several hundreds of thousands of models.Model objects and (depending on the presence or absence of a blank=True, null=True ForeignKey field) perform certain actions.

Given the following code:

```
class RelatedItem(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class Item(models.Model):
  related_item = models.ForeignKey(RelatedItem)

items = Item.objects.all()
for item in items:
  if item.related_item:
    # Do stuff
```

I know that the item.related_item will trigger a database lookup. Hoping to avoid this, I was wondering if I could instead do this:

```
items = Item.objects.all()

for item in items:
  if item.related_item_id:
    # Do stuff
```

Would that item.related_item_id still trigger the database call, or is that field stored in the model, and potentially therefore run faster?

EDIT: Note, I'm not even looking to use the related_item, so I don't think I need to employ a select_related or prefetch anything. That said, if the database lookups are inevitable, and that would also speed up my query (and not bog down my machine's memory as 100k items are prefetched) I could also go for that.

EDIT 2: I also can't change the initial queryset from Item.objects.all() to Item.objects.filter(related_item__isnull=False). My example below is a simplification, but the full function needs to iterate through all objects in the database, regardless of whether or not related_item is set. I understand that this means that I can't avoid the database lookup on the Item object, but I'm hoping to avoid the secondary lookups on item.related_item objects if I don't have to have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer when a coworker directed me to the shell_plus method of Django extensions. Running ./manage.py shell_plus --print-sql prints out all database lookups.

Running item.related_item triggers a SQL query, whereas running item.related_item_id does not.

```
>>> item = Item.objects.last()
>>> item.related_id
1064726
>>> item.related_item
SELECT "items_related"."id"
FROM "items_related"
WHERE "items_related"."id" = 1064726
Execution time: 0.000556s [Database: default]
<Related: Related object>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understand your issue, but when you use objects.all(), you create QuerySet that arent evaluted (meaning no database trigger, so no performance issue). However, when you test those id with your if condition, there'll be database call.